# why it's needed a second に in the sentence 東京に行くには何で行きますか?

Tags: particle-に, particle-は

From the answer in another question of this board, 東京に行くには何で行きますか translates as "About you going to Tokyo, how are you going?" . Why is the second "ni" needed in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second に is for marking a purpose. The English equivalent is "(in order) to" as in "Click *to* see it." The more literal translation would be "**To** go to Tokyo, by what do  you go?" This に is frequently used with 行く (`go to + (verb)`).

Japanese Particle *Ni* — Indicating Purpose
http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particle-ni-purpose/

Examples:

> - 本場の寿司を食べに日本に行った。 I went to Japan **to** eat real sushi.
> - 見に来て！ Come and see it!

Comment: is there a way to write the sentence in a less redudant way in japanese? After all what you want to ask is "how do you go to Tokyo?" but you have to adapt it to "To go to Tokyo, by what do you go?" to write it in japanese?

Comment: Yes, 東京にはどうやって行きますか？ = "How do you go to Tokyo?"